# Scifi short story where man is plagued by violent images

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was about a man living in a world where every surface could display pictures. One day he is targeted by a cyber-terrorism attack that displayed gore, violence, and similar on every surface in his vicinity 24/7. Throughout the attack, a voice insistently tells him about various things happening in the world, then asks what he will do about it. He loses his wife and job, but eventually pulls through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it, it's called *Caspar D. Luckinbill, What Are You Going to Do?* (available to read online [here](https://www.wired.com/story/nick-wolven-short-story/)).

> Gunfire rattles on the radio. Neither of us pays attention. I’m used
>   to gunfire now. Violence is my music. When I sit near a radio, it
>   sings of murder. When I stand near an advertisement, it cries.
>
> All media recognize me. They conspire against me. Every magazine I
>   open is a gallery of gore. Every book I read becomes a book of the
>   dead. My news feeds tally the tortured, the vanished, the lost, the
>   disappeared.

I read it in [*The Best American Science Fiction and Fantasy of 2017*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/33413949-the-best-american-science-fiction-and-fantasy-2017).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a quote.

Comment: Much appreciated Valorum